# How to configure Jersey 2.16 on Tomcat 8.5 + Weld 3.0

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, weld

I'm currently running Jersey 2.25.1 in a Tomcat 8.5 container with Weld 3, but fail updating to Jersey 2.26. The problem seems to be the changed hk2 integration. If I try to use the old way, simply adding `jersey-hk2`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

I get a exception:

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: parent must be a org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl instead it is a org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator_$$_jvst4f9_0
    at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.initialize(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:64)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.jrCreate(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:103)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.createLocator(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.<init>(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.<init>(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory$Hk2InjectionManagerStrategy$1.createInjectionManager(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.create(Hk2InjectionManagerFactory.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createInjectionManager(Injections.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.<init>(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.<init>(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker$Builder.build(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createInflector(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createMethodRouter(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createResourceMethodRouters(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.buildModel(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.Routing$Builder.buildStage(Routing.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
```

The new `jersey-cdi2-se` dependency seems to be working only if you are not already have a weld container running.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this yet. I have tried as well. The component we've used so far to integrate with WELD is, as you know, jersey-cdi1x-servlet, but WELD 3 is for CDI 2.0.

Seems the Jersey project needs to create a jersey-cdi2x-servlet integrator artifact.

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I'm also running into this issue.   I see that there's an artifact called 'jersey-cdi2-se' out there now which seems to imply they're working on CDI 2.0 integration.  The maven artifacts even pull in Weld 3.0.0, but the docs to implement it seem lacking.  I couldn't figure it out on my own before needing to move on.

I simply reverted to Weld 2.x and moved on without the CDI 2.0 goodness :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not using servlet integration, just Grizzly http server, though I needed an additional dependency (same Jersey version as you):

```
    <dependency>
        <!-- Jersey integration with Weld -->
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-weld2-se</artifactId>           
    </dependency>
```